# Get id of current inserted item by javascript

Tags: javascript, list-item

I'm currently trying to get the id of my currently iserted item. I'm making a timesheet which user is able to save and retrieve his own timesheet. The thing is that i put the ID of an item in the html code so i know if the item is coming from my list or if it was currently inserted by the user . So i want to know the currently inserted item and put it in my html code so i know that it has been inserted in the list and i have to make an update of that item and not insert it a second time.

Here is how i'm saving/updating current user timesheet

```
if ($(this).find("input").attr("data-ID")) {
                            updateTimesheet($(this).find("input").attr("data-ID"), jobCode, prestation, parseFloat($(this).find("input").val()), dateMonth);
                        }
                        else {
                            entry = webList.addItem(entryCreationInformation);
                            entry.set_item("JobCode", jobCode);
                            entry.set_item("ClientName", prestation);
                            entry.set_item("DateMonth", dateMonth);
                            entry.set_item("Heure",heure);
                            entry.update();
                            context.load(entry);
                            context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);
                        }

function success() {
    //do nothing
}

function fail(sender, args) {
    alert("Call failed. Error: " +
        args.get_message());
}
function updateTimesheet(id,jobCode,clientName,heure,date) {

    var clientContext = context;
    var oList = webList;

    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(parseInt(id));

    oListItem.set_item("JobCode", jobCode);
    oListItem.set_item("ClientName", clientName);
    oListItem.set_item("DateMonth", date);
    oListItem.set_item("Heure", heure);

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    //alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I've tried like getting the entry.ID on query success but it doesn't work. I've also tried to get the id just after the context.exectureQueryAsync in case the entry was updated but doesn't work either.

I tried this solution here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d9c68caa-ddfd-4a68-a32f-d6154546f42e/getting-id-of-newly-inserted-item-with-silverlight?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious but won't work too.

I'm learning Sharepoint on the job so maybe it isn't best solution to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why it deleted my "Hello there!" At the begining? Can't we say hello here? x)

Comment: "Hello" and other greetings are automatically stripped out by the network. We want the posts to be concice and hence all unnecessary information should be left out of your posts :)

Comment: I've tried all solutions from here and nothing worked. Can't we do this with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix

Reference `entry` object by `this` keyword:

```
this.entry = webList.addItem(entryCreationInformation);
```

to make it accessible  in handler, then you could grab list item id:

```
function success() {
    console.log(entry.get_id());
}
```

---

### How to create List Item via CSOM

```
function addListItem(listTitle,itemProps,OnItemAdded,OnItemError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();

    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    for(var propName in itemProps) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, itemProps[propName]) 
    }

    listItem.update();
    context.load(listItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemAdded(listItem);           
        },
        OnItemError
    );
}
```

Then you could replace your code for creating list item with this one:

```
var itemProps = {'JobCode': jobCode, 'ClientName': prestation, 'DateMonth': dateMonth, 'Heure':heure};
addListItem('YourListTitle',itemProps,
function(item){
            console.log(item.get_id());
         },
         function(sender,args){
            console.log('Error occurred while creating an item:' + args.get_message());
         });
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: Tested and it works for me

Comment: I got "entry is undefined" when i do this, there's no typo. I've made entry a global variables. This is how it looks like after changing to what you suggested:

Comment: `this.entry = webList.addItem(entryCreationInformation);
                                this.entry.set_item("JobCode", jobCode);
                                this.entry.set_item("ClientName", prestation);
                                this.entry.set_item("DateMonth", dateMonth);
                                this.entry.set_item("Heure", parseFloat($(this).find("input").val()));
                                this.entry.update();
                                context.load(this.entry);
                                context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);`

Comment: And success methode
 `function success() {
        console.log(entry.get_id());
    }`

Comment: Hmm, let me check it again, will get back to you..

Comment: Still works for me, anyway i strongly recommend you to refactor your code, please find my updated answer (section How to create List Item via CSOM)

Comment: YES! This is working great thank you. Problem Solved.

Comment: Great, glad this helped you :)

Comment: As I understand "context.load(listItem);" is the key here? Thank You much!

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is you want to display recently added item in the same page.  One simple way of doing this is:-

- Create a view,  sort the view by Created and have Item Limit in the
     view to 5( or however number of recent records you want to see.

[image: View Sort Descending by Created]

[image: Limit Items returned from View]

- Add a List View web part on your page,  make sure you select the view
  you have created.
- As soon as you submit item,  You can refresh the page and newest record will show up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `entry` the proper scope to be valid inside the success handler.  The quick and dirty way to do this would be to make it a global variable. Then you can access it in the handler:

```
function success() {
    var id = entry.get_item("ID");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work either