# Get ID of an inserted list item via CSOM

Tags: development, csom

How can I get the ID of a list item that I just inserted in a list using the SP C# client library?

Comment: After adding the Item, get the list items and sort it with creation date and get the first time.

Comment: Maybe you find your answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96493/get-id-of-current-inserted-item-by-javascript

Comment: I see that using JSOM I can use the callback function to grab the ID of the recently inserted but I'm not seeing how to do that using C#

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can refer below sample:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 
List listObj = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName"); 
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem newItem = listObj.AddItem(itemCreateInfo); 
newItem["Title"] = "My New Item!"; 
newItem.Update(); 
context.Load(newItem);//Load the new item
context.ExecuteQuery();  
Console.WriteLine("ID of new item:{0}", newItem.Id);//Get ID
```

Comment: It works! Thanks.